org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException Occurring in IntelliJ Ultimate but not IntelliJ Community edition
I am a student currently learning java and web development and have been using IntelliJ community edition for a few months now. I decided to give IntelliJ Ultimate a try and am encountering org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException when trying to run spring boot web applications. The weird thing is, if I run the same application in Community Edition, I encounter no such error.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>learn</groupId>
    <artifactId>solar-farm</artifactId>``your text``
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Development tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>

This is an example of one such project's pom if it helps at all. Hopefully someone more experienced may be able to point me in the right direction as even my instructor seems to be stumped.
I have tried disabling the Spring Plugins in IntelliJ Ultiamte thinking there may have been a conflict. I have also tried adding
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

To my pom in hopes it was a plugin issue. After spending a decent amount of time on google I am stumped.

most likely you've got configuration differences between the ide's
